# C++ inheritance printing

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I'm working on an inheritance based project for school which involves making several classes stemming from a Person class. There is a student, employee, hourly employee etc.

If I have a class called studentEmployee which inherits from student and hourlyEmployee which is also a Person, is it possible to print all the attributes of studentEmployee at the same time?

To be more specific, Person has the attribute of name, Student has the attribute of major and gpa etc. Is it possible to print all of these attributes at the same time and if so how?

Comment: Hi Sidd, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post your code for others to find the issue. Also, read below links [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [not failing in explaing the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: sub-class has access to members of base class. in your example both Person and Student class attributes are accessible inside studentEmployee.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use **virtual** function PrintAttributes(for example), defined somewhere in Student or Person classes, and overrided in child classes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about multiple enteries but if you have one each class, you can simply use the attributes of the parent class to call siblings, use attribute name as unique property for all other class, thus whenever you use that name the specific class will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cout` for any type of the stream. But you should define the `<<` with this function for your object:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, your_object & obj)
{
     return os << obj.a << obj.b;
}
```